# What is the difference between peer-to-peer and 'normal' file downloading?

Tags: networking, download

The title says it all:

What is the difference between peer-to-peer and 'normal' file downloading?

This question has always foxed me, can someone explain it?

Comment: Offtopic. Not relevant to software dev, and shows minimal interest in just googling for an answer.

Comment: @Jarmund Ok, Thank you, i'm relatively knew to stack exchange so I wasn't very experienced when using the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is really the right place to ask this, but anyway:

When p2p is used, the files are stored locally on the users' computers and just transferred over network using stuff like torrents.

"Normal" file downloading is when the files are stored on a dedicated web server that makes them publicly accessible.

Anyway, how about use google next time, this is quite a basic question and you should be able to find the answer in less than 1 min all over the internet.